# removing the matched character in string

Tags: python-3.x

```
original_string ="helloworld"
characters_to_remove="world"
for character in characters_to_remove:
    if original_string.find(character) == -1:
        continue
    else:
       # remove matched character
       original_string = original_string.replace(character,'',1)
print(original_string)
```

---

output:hello

(BUt get getting output is:helol) can any one resolve this issue

Comment: How is this related to the C programming language? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: you remove the first ever occurence of any letter thats in "world" => `"he*l**o*l*"` is the result. works as coded.

Comment: Are you aware of ``str.replace``?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is obvious.

The 'l' in 'world' also appears in 'hello'. So what is happening is two things: your code is removing the first l in hello and then ignoring the l in world, because you are actually looping through 'w','o','r','l','d' just once.

A far better way to do this is to use a *regex* and python's great many string libraries, for example:

```
import re
re.sub('world', '', "helloworld")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the `re` module you can use `find` and `replace` functions to replace the partial string :

```
original_string ="helloworld"
characters_to_remove="world"
pos = original_string.find(characters_to_remove)
original_string = original_string.replace(original_string[pos:pos + len(characters_to_remove)],"")
```